# Estimated LogMultinormalDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

How to use procedures designed for EventData for an event data in the bivariate form? 
That means the bivariate data containing each of the four combinations `{number, number}`,`{number, interval}`, `{interval, number}`, `{interval, interval}`

Procedure `EventData` does not work for bivariate data:

```
data =  {{1., 1.}, {{3., ∞}, 7.}, {7., {2., ∞}}, {{3., ∞}, {2., ∞}}, {3., 7.}, {4., 1} };

EventData@data
```

> EventData: the argument ... is not a valid event specification

Similarly, the use of `EventData` per partes does not work

```
EstimatedDistribution[
  EventData /@  data, 
  LogMultinormalDistribution[{m1,m2}, {{a, b}, {b, c}}]
]
```

> EstimatedDistribution: One or more data points are not support of the process...

What is the right way, if it exists? Or is the only option to direct program the log-likelihood estimate?

Comment: Your data has variable censoring but your `EstimatedDistribution` assumes a `LogMultinormalDistribution` with no censoring.

Comment: You might want to ask the question "How do I estimate a bivariate log-normal distribution when one of the dimensions has some censoring?" at the CrossValidated Stack Exchange site.  For example:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315123/truncated-censored-regression-in-the-multivariate-normal-case.